# Evento Onclick JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Estou testando o Onclick no JS e to estranhando um negócio, ele funciona so quando eu colo no console o `document.querySelector('.a').onclick = teste2();` , ou na primeira vez que executo/abro a página. Se eu clicar no elemento que to pegando, ele não funciona. Por que?

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>

<div class="a">Testando...</div>

    <script>
      
      let teste2 = () => alert(this === window);
      document.querySelector('.a').onclick = teste2();

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método `onClick` recebe uma função para que a mesma seja instanciada quando houver o `click`, no seu exemplo você armazena a função em uma variável e passa ela instanciada quando o correto seria passar somente a variável...

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>

<div class="a">Testando...</div>

    <script>
      
      let teste2 = () => alert(this === window);
      document.querySelector('.a').onclick = teste2;

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Caraca, eu confundi com class em PHP que posso chamar tanto com teste2 e teste2(), viajei legal... Obrigado Felipe!